# How to get the mobile number from facebook login API?

Tags: c#, facebook-login, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my code using which I am trying to get the mobile number from facebook, but I am unable get the mobile number.

```
var identity = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var access_token = identity.FindFirstValue("fb_access_token");
var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email,name,gender"); // specify the email field
Email = myInfo.email;
Name = myInfo.name;
string s = myInfo.gender;
Gender = char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per best of my knowledge, you cannot fetch mobile number. Find the following list of fields you can fetch through the API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/user